# What is the proper method to add missing distributions to a running FreeBSD?

Tags: system-installation, freebsd

My FreeBSD 10.0 machine was installed by the hosting company and they left out several distributions. Specifically: `src/src world/doc world/games world/lib32`

How best to add those back into the mix so that tools like `freebsd-update` will recognize their presence?

My best guess:

```
export BSDINSTALL_DISTDIR=/usr/freebsd-dist
bsdinstall distfetch

export DISTRIBUTIONS="src doc games lib32"
export BSDINSTALL_CHROOT=/
bsdinstall distextract
```

Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably don't actually have to use `bsdinstall`, but it provides a certain degree of confirmation. All this is actually in the man page: [bsdinstall(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?bsdinstall%288%29). I just didn't read carefully enough. For the record:

The download requires 2 environment variables: `DISTRIBUTIONS` and `BSDINSTALL_DISTSITE` (`BSDINSTALL_DISTDIR` is optional and defaults to `/usr/freebsd-dist`). The names listed in `DISTRIBUTIONS` have to match the actual file names (e.g. `doc.txz` rather than `doc`). `BSDINSTALL_DISTSITE` is the download URL. The URL has the side-effect of specifying platform and version (`amd64` and `10.0-RELEASE` below).

The extraction requires 1 more variable to be set: `BSDINSTALL_CHROOT`. In this case, `/` is correct (typical use case, when booted to CD and installing to a new disk, is more likely to be `/mnt`).

```
export DISTRIBUTIONS="src.txz doc.txz games.txz lib32.txz"
export BSDINSTALL_DISTDIR=/var/tmp/freebsd-dist
export BSDINSTALL_DISTSITE="http://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/releases/amd64/10.0-RELEASE"
bsdinstall distfetch

export BSDINSTALL_CHROOT=/
bsdinstall distextract
```